# How to add Rest API endpoint in Vaadin application running with Quarkus

Tags: rest, vaadin, quarkus, vaadin23

I have Vaadin v23.x on Quarkus application forked from: https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-flow-quarkus/

I need to have a simple API endpoint as well

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello from RESTEasy Reactive";
  }
}
```

Right now when I am loading `http://localhost:8080/hello` I am getting Vaadin error.

[image: Error msg]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Vaadin doesn't know the rest resoruces you have created, it just knows it's own routes. Maybe the last post here would help: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14769 eg. set quarkus.resteasy.path or quarkus.resteasy-reactive.path to something not conflicting with Vaadin routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem configure `quarkus.resteasy.path` in `application.propertie`

For example: `quarkus.resteasy.path=/api`

And then API will be available at the URL: http://localhost:8080/api/hello